# A smart way to retrieve allowed file types from plist

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, content-type, uti, nssavepanel

### Scenario:

I like to define the allowed file types (content types) in the `Info.plist` file of my Cocoa application. Therefore, I added them like the following example shows.

```
# Extract from Info.plist
[...]
<key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>public.png</string>
        <key>CFBundleTypeIconFile</key>
        <string>png.icns</string>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Viewer</string>
        <key>LSIsAppleDefaultForType</key>
        <true/>
        <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>public.png</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
[...]
```

Further, my application allows to open files using an `NSOpenPanel`. The panel allows to set the allowed file types through the following selector: `setAllowedFileTypes:`. The [documentation states that UTI can be used](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSSavePanel_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSSavePanel).

> The file type can be a common file extension, or a UTI.

---

### A custom solution:

I wrote the following helper method to extract the UTI from the `Info.plist` file.

```
/**
    Returns a collection of uniform type identifiers as defined in the plist file.
    @returns A collection of UTI strings.
 */
+ (NSArray*)uniformTypeIdentifiers {
    static NSArray* contentTypes = nil;
    if (!contentTypes) {
        NSArray* documentTypes = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"CFBundleDocumentTypes"];
        NSMutableArray* contentTypesCollection = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[documentTypes count]];
        for (NSDictionary* documentType in documentTypes) {
            [contentTypesCollection addObjectsFromArray:[documentType objectForKey:@"LSItemContentTypes"]];
        }
        contentTypes = [NSArray arrayWithArray:contentTypesCollection];
        contentTypesCollection = nil;
    }
    return contentTypes;
}
```

Instead of `[NSBundle mainBundle]` also `CFBundleGetInfoDictionary(CFBundleGetMainBundle())` can be used.

---

### Questions:

1. Do you know a smarter way to extract the content type information
   from the `Info.plist` file? Is there  a Cocoa-build-in function?
2. How do you deal with the definition of folders that can contained
   there, e.g. `public.folder`?

**Note:**
Throughout my research, I found this article quite informative: [Simplifying Data Handling with Uniform Type Identifiers](http://web.archive.org/web/20101203201225/http://developer.apple.com/macosx/uniformtypeidentifiers.html).

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I read information from a plist (it can be the info.plist or any other plist you have in you project provided you set the correct path)

```
NSString *resourcePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath];
NSString *fullPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/path/to/your/plist/my.plist", resourcePath];
NSData *plistData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:fullPath];
NSDictionary *plistDictionary = [NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListFromData:plistData mutabilityOption:NSPropertyListImmutable format:0 errorDescription:nil];
NSArray *fileTypes = [plistDictionary objectForKey:@"CFBundleDocumentTypes"];
```

Comment: I like `NSPropertyListSerialization` you use. Though, your solution needs to know the path to the plist file. - How about the second part of my question?

Comment: I am not sure I understand the second part of your question if you can clarify it some more I would be happy to try and find a solution for you.

Comment: As far as I understood you can specify UTIs for individual file types, a group of file types like `public.image` and for folders `public.folder`. How do you allow to open images (single/multiple/folder) in your application via `file/open` and `drag-n-drop onto the application icon`? Please avoid redundant definitions of UTIs.